# What is the initial piano chord in Ella and Louie's "I Won't Dance" recording?

Tags: chords, technique, chord-theory, keyboard

I'm learning this song for a duet performance. I can play the walking bass line and even the chord progressions on bass. I can even tap out the intro chords when the lyrics start in a Stu Hamm or Victor Wooten fashion (just an example so you don't question why I'm playing chords on bass). However, in the very beginning of the song the piano runs through (what I believe to be) an Eb chord. Now let me remind you I don't play piano. I play violin, autoharp, and bass, so I'm not very familiar with any piano techniques. But let me assure you I've heard this style of a run-up before. I've tried several ways of tapping out this chord in a very fast manner, but I just can't seem to make out all these notes, or quite frankly, what's going on here.

Comment: Get some software that can slow down the audio without changing the pitch - e.g. Audacity, or (specifically written for music transcribing) the demo version of "Transcribe". If you play it say 10 times slower than the original you should be able to pick out the notes. "Knowing about piano technique" wouldn't help - a good pianist can play any notes that he/she wants to in that sort of run!

Comment: @alephzero - with all the technology available, skill is taking a back seat. I wonder when our ears will become vestigial...

Comment: I agree, it's quiet a shame. I understand it makes things much easier, but even now, computers can replace instruments in a hardbeat. So much modern music is synthetic and without soul or feel.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like a diminished 7th arpeggio to me - same sort of thing that starts 'I Will Survive', except this rolls from Eb up to C. Taking the song into Ab.

Answer (score 0):

The chord is an Eb7b9(add13).

The piano plays an Eb octave, arpeggiates a G<sup>o7</sup> up a total of 7 notes (`G Bb Db E G Bb Db`), steps back down to the Bb, and resumes the arpeggio for a total of 8 more notes (`Bb Db E G Bb Db E G`), and finally ends on a C.